# How to validate and convert forward slash to start of url

Tags: javascript

```
var path1 = 'catalog/view/theme/default/image/flags/usa.png';

var path2 = '../catalog/view/theme/default/image/flags/usa.png';

var path3 =  '/catalog/view/theme/default/image/flags/usa.png';

var path4 =  '__catalog/view/theme/default/image/flags/usa.png';

var path5 =  '@catalog/view/theme/default/image/flags/usa.png';

var path6 =  '%catalog/view/theme/default/image/flags/usa.png';

var path7 =  '?catalog/view/theme/default/image/flags/usa.png';
```

What would the regex be to ensure and prefix / to the start of a url string
The result shoud be /catalog/view/theme/default/image/flags/usa.png

Comment: Can you elaborate on why `var path = '/catalog/view/theme/default/image/flags/usa.png';` is undesirable and a regex is more appropriate? (Is the path fixed, does it have any significance, are the only variations listed above, ...)

Comment: I am getting the src from img tags. I want to make absolute url format like http://www.server.com/path/file.jpg. Some src links are starting with '../', or no forward slash.

Comment: Just truncating anything foreign prefixing `content/` should work, however that is the sledge hammer to a finishing nail approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
var url='/'+path2.match(/[a-z].*/gi); // use path1 to path7
console.log(url);​​ // Result is: /catalog/view/theme/default/image/flags/usa.png
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
       '/' + path2.match(/catalog.*/)
```

Answer (score 0):

The regex

```
/^\/.*$/
```

will match a beginning slash.

```
/^[^\/].*$/
```

will match a string WITHOUT a beginning slash.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:

```
var patern =/[a-z].+$/gi;
var use = '/'+'__catalog/view/theme/default/image/flags/usa.png'.match(/[a-z].+$/gi)[0];
//use === "/catalog/view/theme/default/image/flags/usa.png"
```

There you go